# as3 array match a number anywhere in an array and return that number and values on same row

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3

Here is the array:

```
var level:Array = new Array( 5 );    //there are five rows

level[0] = [0.01, 0.6116, 0.001000, 206.14, 0.00, 2375.3, 0.00, 2501.4, 0.0000, 9.1562]
level[1] = [5, 0.8721, 0.001000, 147.12, 20.97, 2382.3, 20.98, 2510.6, 0.0761, 9.0257]
level[2] = [10, 1.2276, 0.001000, 106.38, 42.00, 2389.2, 42.01, 2519.8, 0.1510, 8.9008]
level[3] = [15, 1.7051, 0.001001, 77.93, 62.99, 2396.1, 62.99, 2528.9, .02245, 8.7814]
level[4] = [20, 2.339, 0.001002, 57.79, 83.95, 2402.9, 83.96, 2538.1, 0.2966, 8.6672]
```

I want to input a number and find a match for the number, returning the values on the row in to specific fields for each number. For example, if I input the number 10 in an input field, I want the number 1.2276, 0.00100, 106.38 and the rest of that row to output these values

I have seen so many options, don't know where to start. Thanks.

Comment: Is the data structure final or are you ok to modify it?

Comment: Sure, it can be changed. I am open to all suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using a `Dictionary` rather than an `Array` for this. This way you can assign key's to the `Array` objects and access the arrays by key.

```
var level:Dictionary = new Dictionary();

level[0.01] = [0.6116, 0.001000, 206.14, 0.00, 2375.3, 0.00, 2501.4, 0.0000, 9.1562];
level[5] = [0.8721, 0.001000, 147.12, 20.97, 2382.3, 20.98, 2510.6, 0.0761, 9.0257];
level[10] = [1.2276, 0.001000, 106.38, 42.00, 2389.2, 42.01, 2519.8, 0.1510, 8.9008];
level[15] = [1.7051, 0.001001, 77.93, 62.99, 2396.1, 62.99, 2528.9, .02245, 8.7814];
level[20] = [2.339, 0.001002, 57.79, 83.95, 2402.9, 83.96, 2538.1, 0.2966, 8.6672];

function getArrayByInputText(txt:String):Array {
    return level[txt];
}

trace(getArrayByInputText("10")); // [1.2276, 0.001000, 106.38, 42.00, 2389.2, 42.01, 2519.8, 0.1510, 8.9008];
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a simple `for` loop.

```
for (var i:int=0; i<level.length; i++) {
     if (level[i].indexOf(input) > -1) { // check array for index of input
         trace(level[i]);
         break; // stop loop because we're done
     }
}
```

Comment: This shows all values in the array. How can I show only the values say on level 3?

Comment: Do you mean values in `level[i]` or all other values not your input? This loop will recursively go through each array in the `level` array and search for your input. Once found it will stop the loop

Comment: I want the input value to be returned along with the values that are found on the same row. The input value could be any number in the array. All values on that row where the input value matches, I want to output these numbers.

Comment: I've turned this into a JavaScript example for working model purposes. Maybe you can explain the question better? http://jsfiddle.net/jdgiotta/AZq9z/3/

Comment: Seems like it will work. Look at the array. I input a 42. I want all the numbers on that row only to output along with the 42.00. I am learning and sure my question is not clear. Does this help?       10, 1.2276, 0.001000, 106.38, 42.00, 2389.2, 42.01, 2519.8, 0.1510, 8.9008  because 42.00 matches this level it outputs the numbers on this row.